# SQL Import Export Wizard : not allowing saving packages

Tags: import, export, wizard

I have installed SQL Server 2012 Express Edition in my laptop a long ago.  Recently, I installed the SQL server 2012 developer edition.

The problem is when I launch the Import Export wizard it is automatically launching the version attached to the express edition.  Apparently, this is a shared feature.  How can I upgrade Import Export wizard for getting the full functionality?

I was trying to export some tables from a SQL server 2012 developer instance to another developer instance.By the express wizard version I can not save the Import Export package, but I can run it immediately.

The message is "In SQL Server Express, Web, or Workgroup, you can run the package that the Import and Export Wizard creates, but cannot save it. To save packages that the wizard creates, you must upgrade to SQL Server Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation."  But I already have Developer edition in my laptop. So which software packages I have to upgrade and how?

Please advise me about this problem.

Thanks,
Deeps

Comment: Hi all,I got the solution.  I ran the set up file again and added shared features to the instance.  Now I can save and run packages in Export Import wizard.